# Import 3rd Party Dependancy into Swift Framework

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I have a framework let's call it myFramework. I need to import Starscream a 3rd party dep into my framework.

I have tried using Swift Package Manager. I add the Package to the project, then link to the Framework target. Inside of the myFramework target I see Starscream listed as a library inside of "Link Binary With Libraries". When I build it succeeds, but if I import Starscream into a file, it comes up with the error "No such module".

Is this possible?

Comment: You can’t include a framework in a framework but you can include a framework in a package

Comment: @loremipsum So I cannot include a swift package in my framework but I can include a framework if I make it a swift package? Very confused. If I have an existing framework that I need to add in a 3rd party dependency, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: It cannot be done. Apple does not allow frameworks inside frameworks.